# Unicode-math using Verdana

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I've recently begun teaching physics in a high school and I need to prepare a test for a dyslexia-affected child. I'm forced by her doctor to write the exam text in Verdana, so I also must write data and formulae in that font. How can I input Verdana glyphs using the package `unicode-math`?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick-and-dirty fix, which makes use of the `mathastext` package. Upper- and lowercase letters in math mode will be from Verdana.

[image]

```
%% Compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}

abcdefg -- text

$abcdefg$  -- math

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

$e^{i\pi}-1=0$
\end{document}
```